# Is this something known in RestAssured? the first dataset query parameters are concatenated in the second trigger instance of the endpoint

Tags: java, rest, cucumber, rest-assured

I am currently working a GET endpoint using rest-assured/cucumber/java, That takes the query param from the examples section of the feature file, The code works fine if there is only one data set, as soon as I use another dataset in that case it take the both the dataset values.

**Feature file:**

```
  Scenario Outline: Verify response size parameter matches the input size
    Given Asset with projectId "<projectId>" is used
    When user calls the getScenePaginationAPI endpoint with the GET request with "<size>"
    Then API call triggers response with status code 200
    And "size" in the response is "<size>"

    Examples:
      |         projectId                  | size |
      |378cbcc5-3e85-463e-a938-db9ee6a9aff0|  2   |
      |12b1d56a-9db5-4fd7-acbb-5e457ce7f30e|  4   |
```

**StepDef File:**

```
  @When("^user calls the getScenePaginationAPI endpoint with the GET request with \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void user_calls_the_getScenePaginationAPI_endpoint_with_the_GET_request_with(int size) throws IOException {
    req = given().relaxedHTTPSValidation().urlEncodingEnabled(false).spec(RequestSpecification())
            .queryParam("size",size);
    String resourceAPI = endpointResources.getScenePaginationAPI();
    resp = new ResponseSpecBuilder().expectContentType(ContentType.JSON).build();
    response = req.when().get(resourceAPI);
    logger.info("Response Data: "+response);
}
```

**Log file:**

**Taking the 1st dataset**

```
Request method: GET
Request URI:    https://testing.company.com/g1/projects/378cbcc5-3e85-463e-a938-db9ee6a9aff0/scenes?size=2
```

**When taking the 2nd dataset**

```
Request method: GET
Request URI:    https://testing.company.com/g1/projects/12b1d56a-9db5-4fd7-acbb-5e457ce7f30e/scenes?size=2&size=4
```

Answer (score 1):

After receiving the response, make req as null.

after this line,

response = req.when().get(resourceAPI);
req=null;